# How do I set a string list of email attachments with httpPostedFileBase files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email-attachments

On my MVC project I have a Order form with two Upload fields.

I'm trying to attach to email the uploaded documents but can't get it to work.

My send email function expects a list of attachments and a list of attachments names as follow:

```
public class Email
{
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string CC { get; set; }
    public string Bcc { get; set; }
    public List<string> Attachments { get; set; }
    public List<string> AttachmentsNames { get; set; }
}
```

And the function that submit the form:

```
public ActionResult SubmitOrder(Order order)
{
public OrderViewModel oViewModel = new OrderViewModel();
oViewModel.email = new Email();
oViewModel.email.To = "test@test.test";
oViewModel.email.CC = "test@test.test";
oViewModel.email.Subject = "Order";
oViewModel.email.From = "info@test.com";
oViewModel.email.Bcc = "test@test.test";
oViewModel.email.Body = "<html><body><table border=0>" +
                       //content of the form
                        "</table></body></html>";

List<string> attachments = new List<string>(new string[] { order.file1.InputStream });
//I'm getting the error at this point
List<string> attachmentsNames = new List<string>(new string[] { order.file1.FileName});

oViewModel.email.Attachments = attachments;
oViewModel.email.AttachmentsNames = attachmentsNames;
//rest of code that actually send the email
}
```

As you can see I tried: `file1.InputStream` (`file1` is of type `httpPostedFileBase`) but got a conversion error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.Stream' to 'string'

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: input stream is a stream so I figure you would need to get the stream data and encode it as a string to satisfy the object's requirement

Comment: What is type of file is `file1`? How can you be sure that this will convert to a string (even using @Nkosi's suggestion) succesfully? Why are you abstracting to your own `Email` class, in the first place? Does the `MailMessage` class not suffice to your requirements?

Comment: `file1` is of type `HttpPostedFileBase`, I have to abstract my own `Email` class because we have an API that sends emails for all our projects and there the `Email` class is defined and I have to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the uploaded files to disk and then pass the file location to email

```
//...other code
var attachments = new List<string>();
var attachmentsNames = new List<string>();
var file = order.file1;
if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/attachments"), fileName);
    file.SaveAs(filePath);//save the file to disk
    //add file path and name to collections.
    attachments.Add(filePath);
    attachmentsNames.Add(fileName);        
}

//...other code
```

I would also check to make sure that the uploaded files are deleted/removed after it is confirmed that the email is sent otherwise there is a possibility of running out of disk space.

UPDATE: based on comment

> Given that the email portion is custom code that you all use I would
>   first check to see if that is already deleting the files after sending
>   the emails. If not then in the part where you say `//rest of code that
>   actually send the email`, after sending the email you can simply
>   traverse the attachments list and delete the file based on paths.

```
//rest of code that actually send the email
foreach(var path in attachments) {
    if(File.Exists(path)) File.Delete(path);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is the answer that I get  from the server when I try to send the email: `"Error:The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.\"` The `attachment` looks like a weird long string: `"UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCnlfmZhAEAABQ"` etc...

Comment: Then that means that the attachments collection does not stored the content of the file but rather the path to where to find the file. You are going to have to save the uploaded file temporarily on the server and pass the path of the file to the attachments collection. the weird string is the base64 representation of the file contents.

Comment: Can't update answer now. will update full answer with this new information later.

Comment: I do hope that you understand what i mean by having to save the file to disk and then passing the file path to the email.

Comment: @user3378165 check updated answer. off to meeting. will check back later.

Comment: Excellent! Working perfectly! Thank you soooo much!! Just one last question- at which point would you delete the uploaded document from the disk? Would you be able to give me an example? Thank you!!

Comment: Given that the email portion is custom code that you all use I would first check to see if that is already deleting the files after sending the emails. If not then in the part where you say `//rest of code that actually send the email`, after sending the email you can simply traverse the attachments list and delete the file based on paths. `foreach(var path in attachments) File.Delete(path);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wish I could vote more than once! There is no such a code on the Send Email function so I did as you suggested and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Included it in the answer then. Maybe it will help someone else later on who may have a similar problem.

Comment: I keep getting an error on the delete line that the `file is used by another process` and I'm sure I'm the only one that uses the files, any idea why?

Comment: it is possible that the email sending process has the file stream still open when you try to delete file. is the email process disposable? if so then you need to make sure the the email process releases any resources that it was using after it is finished sending the email.

Comment: It wasn't disposing the attachments after the mail sending... I added this code and it works fine, you are a real genius!!!

Comment: Genius? no. just encountered similar problems before and passing on the knowledge. The more you code the more you recognize certain issues and their causes.

Comment: Hope to feel like this one day:)